# how to forward request from apache to s3

Tags: apache, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a hosted website on fasthost DNS provider with the name `mywebsite.com`. Any request to mywebsite.com gets forwarded to a running on aws EC2 instance on which my web application is running. In the EC2 instance, I have setup Apache http server that takes all the requests and forward to my web application with the help of the following virtual host setting in the apache `httpd.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests Off
     ServerName mywebsite.com
     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

So far this is working fine. Now I have static image which I have hosted on aws S3 bucket. The publicly accessible url is `https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/static/images/some-img.png`

I do not want the S3 domain-name appear and would like to mask `s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` server name so instead of `https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/static/images/some-img.png` I have something like 
https://mywebsite.com/static/images/some-img.png
I tried adding the Virtual host entry in httpd.conf so that any request with context `/static` gets forwarded to S3 instance. but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests Off
     ServerName mywebsite.com
     ProxyPass /static https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/
     ProxyPassReverse /static https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea if this is at all possible?

**Update**
I modified the VirtualHost to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ErrorLog logs/mywebsite.com-error_log
     ProxyPreserveHost Off
     ProxyRequests Off
     ServerName mywebsite.com
     ProxyPass /static https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mywebsite-static-repo
     ProxyPassReverse /static https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mywebsite-static-repo

</VirtualHost>
```

Where `mywebsite-static-repo` is the name of the bucket. The `mywebsite.com-error_log` gives the following error:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/html/mywebsite-static-repo
[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /static/mywebsite-static-repo/images/some-img.png. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Comment: I misread your question so I deleted my answer. You should consider setting up Cloudfront with your custom domain and connecting it to your S3 server to avoid redirection overheads for the incoming connections etc on your EC2, and CF also gives you tons of other benefits in the long run.

Comment: This is definitely possible, but you want `ProxyPreserveHost` set to `off` and include the bucket name in the `ProxyPass` directive, either as `...aws.com/bucket/` or `https://bucket.s3....`. Please don't say "it doesn't seem to be working."  Describe the behavior.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have updated the question with your suggestion.

Comment: @tintin could it be that you hadn't mod_proxy_http or mod_ssl enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I had a bucket setup in the `us-west-2` region, and no matter what I did, I couldn't get the ProxyPass to work. As a last resort, I deleted the bucket and recreated it in the default region (`us-east-1`). Then finally the ProxyPass worked. Here's how it's setup (yes, I know the bucket name is in there twice):

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
ProxyPass        /static/ https://<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>/
ProxyPassReverse /static/ https://<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>/
```

So it appears that S3 just can't accept the proxied requests in regions other than the default (unless there's some header you can send that I'm not aware of).

One thing I didn't try until after I had already moved the bucket is using a [RewriteRule with the proxy flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p):

```
RewriteRule "/static/(.*)$" "https://<bucket_name>.s3.amazonaws.com/$1" [P]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the problem resolved by setting proper Host header

To find out whats actually happening, I tried to proxy httpbin.org

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests Off
     ServerName www.example.org

    <Location /get>
         ProxyPass http://httpbin.org/get
         ProxyPassReverse  http://httpbin.org/get
         RequestHeader set "Host" "httpbin.org"
         RequestHeader unset Cookie
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

check it with curl

curl -s "http://www.example.org/get?foo=bar"

```
{
  "args": {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.64.1",
    "X-Forwarded-Host": "httpbin.org",
    "X-Forwarded-Server": "www.example.org"
  },
  "origin": "---",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar"
}
```

** bonus: I found out that to be safe, I needed to remove cookie header too..

then I tried it with s3 bucket --- please avoid trailing slash (also remove static from s3 url if it is not intended)

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequests Off
     ServerName www.example.org

     <Location /static>
       ProxyPass  http://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/static
       ProxyPassReverse  http://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/static
       RequestHeader set "Host" "BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com"
       RequestHeader unset Cookie
     </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```